# add square or triangle markers (not circles) to R plotly map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I can plot circle markers on a map as in this example.  But I want to change the marker shape from circles to squares in add_markers, but I can't find the solution in the help(add_markers) or online examples.  I tried to add type=list("squares") but it didn't change anything unfortunately.

```
require(plotly)

df<- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_ebola.csv')
# restrict from June to September
df <- subset(df, Month %in% 6:9)
# ordered factor variable with month abbreviations
df$abbrev <- ordered(month.abb[df$Month], levels = month.abb[6:9])
# September totals
df9 <- subset(df, Month == 9)

p <- df %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode = 'country names', sizes = c(1, 600), color = I("black")
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    y = ~Lat, x = ~Lon, locations = ~Country,
    size = ~Value, color = ~abbrev, text = ~paste(Value, "cases")
  ) 
p
```

Comment: Perhaps you can look at `symbol`: https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a parameter called `symbol`. You can use

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode = 'country names', sizes = c(1, 600), color = I("black")
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    y = ~Lat, x = ~Lon, locations = ~Country,
    size = ~Value, color = ~abbrev, text = ~paste(Value, "cases"),
    symbol = ~abbrev
  ) 
p
```

You also can specify the symbols, using

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode = 'country names', sizes = c(1, 600), color = I("black")
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    y = ~Lat, x = ~Lon, locations = ~Country,
    size = ~Value, color = ~abbrev, text = ~paste(Value, "cases"),
    symbol = ~abbrev, symbols = c('circle', 'square', 'x', 'triangle')
  ) 
p
```

And if you want just switch the circle to another symbol, use:

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_geo(
    locationmode = 'country names', sizes = c(1, 600), color = I("black")
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    y = ~Lat, x = ~Lon, locations = ~Country,
    size = ~Value, color = ~abbrev, text = ~paste(Value, "cases"),
    symbol = 'triangle'
  ) 
p
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "triangle-up" works instead "triangle" for me (plotly_4.9.2.1)